# How to implement AsyncTask for twitter.getAccountSettings(): Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j in my application. I am using below code to check if auth token expired or user not logged in yet

```
public static boolean isAuthenticated(Context context) {

        TwitterPrefrences twitterPref = new TwitterPrefrences(context);     
        String token = twitterPref.getTwitterAuthToken();
        String secret = twitterPref.getTwitterAuthTokenSecrate();

        AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.TWITT_CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.TWITT_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

        try {
            twitter.getAccountSettings();
            return true;
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

But I am getting following error

```
 05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:479)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:45)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:178)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:75)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:103)
    05-02 19:52:23.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at 

twitter4j.Twitter.getAccountSettings(Twitter.java:1440)
```

Caller code as

```
chbTwOption.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked) {
                    boolean showTwlogin = false;
                    if ("No".equalsIgnoreCase(twitPref.getTwitterAuthToken())
                            || "No".equalsIgnoreCase(twitPref.getTwitterAuthTokenSecrate())) {
                        showTwlogin = true;
                    } else {                        
                        showTwlogin = TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(AddSchedule.this);
                    }   

                    if(showTwlogin) {
                        showSocialMediaLoginMessage(Constants.TW_LOGIN_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Its clear that I have to implement `AsyncTask` for `twitter.getAccountSettings()`  but how can I get result as a method from `AsyncTask`? Is there any other way to check auth token expire? Or how can I implement `AsyncTask` as a method which will return result as `isAuthenticated()` as I used.

Please guide me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at the source for [Zwitscher](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA)
and here especially at [TwitterLoginActivity](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/account/TwitterLoginActivity.java)

Comment: +1 Thank you! I got an idea from TwitterLoginActivity code. And I made my work. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might got this error most probably in 4.0 device or IF the http conncetion is taking too long to respond.

if you dont know asynctask  then simple solution will be

```
 public static boolean isAuthenticated(Context context) {
        new Thread() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
        TwitterPrefrences twitterPref = new TwitterPrefrences(context);     
        String token = twitterPref.getTwitterAuthToken();
        String secret = twitterPref.getTwitterAuthTokenSecrate();

        AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
             twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.TWITT_CONSUMER_KEY,Constants.TWITT_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

        try {
            twitter.getAccountSettings();
            return true;
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            return false;
        }
      }
     }.start();

    }
```

But the better way would be implemting asynctask.

thanks
   santhu

Comment: user187928 how can I do that?

Comment: Note that you will see warnings or kills from 2.3 on with strict mode enabled. In Android3+ this is on by default. So better get this right for 2.3 too.